# How to permanently remove Growl from my Mac

Tags: macos, growl

Growl just installed itself on my machine without me requesting it and it has now infected everything - every program I open how do I get rid of it?

Comment: Most likely Growl was installed by another app you installed.  That install program *should* have asked you or at least notified you that Growl was a requirement.  Bad Programmer!  Bad!

Comment: Popup Notifications Automatically = Evil/Infection. Funny how much turnaround we have here.

Comment: It's unfortunate that you're confused because some application installed Growl without your permission, but Growl never just "installs itself" nor should it activate with "every program". It's a notification framework, not an infection. Read @Rich Homolka's answer. Relax. And direct your complaint to the developer of whatever application installed it without telling you. Jerks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A simple search finds http://growl.info/documentation/growl-package-removal.php from the growl official site.  It also has this page http://growl.info/thirdpartyinstallations.php which may explain how it got on your machine.  You should read it, or you may find it on your machine again.

Growl is just a notifier, you can turn it off in Preferences if you don't like it, or configure only specific apps to use it.

Answer (score 3):

Go to the [Growl Website](http://growl.info/) download it, then run the uninstaller contained in the disk image.

Answer (score 2):

i have found http://freemacsoft.net/AppCleaner/ to be particularly useful for all purposes.