# How can I remove Growl from my OS X system?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, growl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to permanently remove GROWL from my Mac](https://superuser.com/questions/192439/how-to-permanently-remove-growl-from-my-mac)

I have Growl pop-up notifications on my OS X 10.6.4 Snow Leopard system, and there's also a Growl control panel in my System Preferences dialog.

However, there is no "Growl" in my Applications dir or in Applications/Utilities.

A search using Spotlight turns up nothing.

How can I completely clean Growl off of my system?

Comment: Duplicate of: http://superuser.com/questions/192439/how-to-permanently-remove-growl-from-my-mac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Growl website](http://growl.info/documentation/growl-package-removal.php):

> To uninstall Growl:
>
> 1. Download the [Growl uninstaller](http://growl.info/files/Uninstall%20Growl.zip).
> 2. Run it.